# Richfaces javascript and css does not load when I remove faces-redirect from menu item

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, richfaces

I am using Richfaces 4.x in my web application. I use richfaces rich:panelMenu component to create my menu. I also have a backing bean for navigation purpose, which is a sessionScoped ManagedBean. When I use faces redirect in my code and use something like following code my page load all CSS and Javascript properly:

`return "mypackagespath/../mypage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"`

The problem is that when I remove "?faces-redirect=true" from the statement, the page doesn't load most richfaces related javascript and CSS styles properly in first load, although when I submit an action on my page those CSS and scripts load properly.

Has anyone faced the same issue before? Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't load". Do you get 404s? Or what's wrong?

Comment: Means that forwards are not going thru the FacesServlet or something. The question now would be why. Could you post your web.xml here?

Comment: Is the ajax request handled by RichFaces (i.e. `<a4j:xxx>`) or standard JSF (i.e. `<f:ajax>`)? Have you tried the other way?